# SQL Repeat values where value is NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created a summary view and using following query to get results

```
    SELECT captain.Name AS Name,
      rides.date AS date,
      rides.tr AS tr,
      rides.cr AS cr,
      rides.cg AS cg,
      rides.p AS p,
      rides.oe AS oe,
      (((rides.cr + rides.cg) - (rides.p +
      rides.oe)) - rides.tih) AS short,
     rides.tih AS tih,
     ct.tr AS tr,
     ct.ca AS ca
   FROM (rides
     JOIN captain ON captain.captainID = rides.captainID)
     JOIN ct ON captain.captainID = ct.captainID
```

output like this

```
date      tr    cr  cg  p   oe  short   tih tr  ca
---------------------------------------------------
12/6/2017 20    10  10  2   3    4      43  1   88
13/6/2017 10    9   9   2   3    1      56  1   88
14/6/2017 20    10  10  2   3    4      43  1   88
15/6/2017 10    9   9   2   3    1      56  1   88
16/6/2017 20    10  10  2   3    4      43  1   88
17/6/2017 10    9   9   2   3    1      56  1   88
```

But it should be

```
date      tr    cr  cg  p   oe  short   tih tr  ca
---------------------------------------------------
12/6/2017 20    10  10  2   3    4      43  0   0
13/6/2017 10    9   9   2   3    1      56  0   0
14/6/2017 20    10  10  2   3    4      43  0   0
15/6/2017 10    9   9   2   3    1      56  0   0
16/6/2017 20    10  10  2   3    4      43  1   88
17/6/2017 10    9   9   2   3    1      56  1   88
```

because in ct table I have only two records for 16 and 17 June.
How to force to show 0 when no records available.

Hope that I have explained properly what i need. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to join by date in ct table as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join on `date` as well with `ct table.` Use `case when` to substitute blank values to 0

Try this:-

```
   SELECT captain.Name AS Name,
      rides.date AS date,
      rides.tr AS tr,
      rides.cr AS cr,
      rides.cg AS cg,
      rides.p AS p,
      rides.oe AS oe,
      (((rides.cr + rides.cg) - (rides.p +
      rides.oe)) - rides.tih) AS short,
     rides.tih AS tih,
     case when ct.tr is NULL and ct.tr=' ' then 0 else ct.tr END AS tr,
     case when ct.ca is NULL and ct.ca=' ' then 0 else ct.ca END AS ca,
   FROM (rides
     JOIN captain ON captain.captainID = rides.captainID)
    LEFT JOIN ct ON rides.captainID = ct.captainID and rides.date=ct.date
```

Comment: You need to use `LEFT JOIN` if there are no records that match the date.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the input. Corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT JOIN` (left outer join) on the last line.

```
SELECT captain.Name AS Name,
  rides.date AS date,
  rides.tr AS tr,
  rides.cr AS cr,
  rides.cg AS cg,
  rides.p AS p,
  rides.oe AS oe,
  (((rides.cr + rides.cg) - (rides.p +
  rides.oe)) - rides.tih) AS short,
 rides.tih AS tih,
 ct.tr AS tr,
 ct.ca AS ca
 FROM (rides
 JOIN captain ON captain.captainID = rides.captainID)
 LEFT JOIN ct ON (captain.captainID = ct.captainID and rides.date=ct.date)
```

Comment: He also needs to add the date to the join condition.

Comment: Could you explain little bit in detail please?